# Can't get webscraped data into SQLite table

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I am hoping someone can help me with a problem I've been scratching my head over for a week now. I have built a webscraper that can scrape various information about cafes from an aggregator site (name, address, description etc.).

My goal is to store the scraped info in a database using SQLite3 (I have chosen this because it seemed easiest for a beginner to get into and there are good tutorials).

I have created the database and a simple 1 column table as a starting point just to store the cafe names with the plan to add on further columns in the future.

The problem I am having now is making the webscraper and the database connect... I am trying to make it when the program is run the scraped cafe names are sent directly into the database. Here is the code:

```
def insertVariableIntoTable(name):

    url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury' #go to the website
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    type(soup_cafe_names)

    cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", }) #scrape the elements
    cafeNames = [ul.text.strip() for ul in cafeNames] #clean the elements

    try:
        sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO newTable
                            (name)
                            VALUES
                            (?)"""
                            
        data_tuple = cafeNames
        cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Python Variables inserted successfully into table ")

        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert data into sqlite table", error)
    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("The SQLite connection is closed")
```

I'm currently getting an error: `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied. The SQLite connection is closed`

But sometimes it doesn't throw an error at all but when I check the table in the database nothing has ended up there.

Thank you for taking the time to have a look.

Comment: ? = 1 value. Not a list of N (5) values. That means the usage on executemany is suspect.. (ie. see the documentation and examples)

Comment: ie. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html - note that the parameters are a *sequence-of* sequence, such as: [(“James”,), (“Mary”,)], ..

Comment: Thanks for the response, so let’s say the scraper pulls 10 names, do I then need 10x? I thought ? Was just a placeholder for column “name”.

Comment: It is. However, the current code does not call the executemany function correctly. Perhaps cafeNames should be a *list of tuple(string)* and not a *list of string*.

Comment: What I seem to be missing by my reading of the documentation is a sequence of parameters for executemany to iterate through?